# Hierarchical Class design

Tags: c#, class-design

Let's consider I want to create the following hierarchy:

Animal -> Class (mammal, amphibian, ...) -> Family (Felidae, Canidae, ...) -> Species (cat, tiger, ...).

each sub class dependes on the previous one.

Any suggestion on the best methodology for creating a tree-like class similar to this one?

This is just an example of the problem I have at hands but a solution would help me a lot...

thanks

The real problem is this:

I have to parse a message of the following type 0102060800FF.

Firstly, 01 tells me I have a specific type of message.
Given that type, i must look for the value 02 in a specific table, and so on...

I want a subhierarchy's possible values filtered by its parent. I'm not sure if i'm being clear enough.

thanks

Comment: A more concrete example might help.

Comment: In your question you just defined what the purpose of Object Oriented programming is as well as inheritance. From your question I am confused as to what you're trying to do. Are you trying to come up with a class to visually display such a graph? Or are you talking about the structure of the data objects on your program?

Comment: I'm talking about data structure. given the real example i would like to create a hierarchy of class types. If I defined the base calss as Type1 the following possiblities would be limited to a specific range of Types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These days, favor composition over inheritance.  Here's an example - needs some more logic checking to make sure you're adding into the proper hierarchy, etc.

```
public class Class
{
    private readonly IList<Animal> animals = new List<Animal>();

    public IEnumerable<Animal> Animals
    {
        get
        {
            return this.animals;
        }
    }

    public void AddAnimal(Animal animal)
    {
        if (animal == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("animal");
        }

        this.animals.Add(animal);
    }

    //// etc.
}

public class Family
{
    private readonly IList<Animal> animals = new List<Animal>();

    public IEnumerable<Animal> Animals
    {
        get
        {
            return this.animals;
        }
    }

    public void AddAnimal(Animal animal)
    {
        if (animal == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("animal");
        }

        this.animals.Add(animal);
    }

    //// etc.
}

public class Species
{
    private readonly IList<Animal> animals = new List<Animal>();

    public IEnumerable<Animal> Animals
    {
        get
        {
            return this.animals;
        }
    }

    public void AddAnimal(Animal animal)
    {
        if (animal == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("animal");
        }

        this.animals.Add(animal);
    }

    //// etc.
}

public class Animal
{
    private readonly Class @class;
    private readonly Family family;
    private readonly Species species;

    public Animal(Class @class, Family family, Species species)
    {
        if (@class == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("@class");
        }

        if (family == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("family");
        }

        if (species == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("species");
        }

        this.@class = @class;
        this.family = family;
        this.species = species;
        this.@class.AddAnimal(this);
        this.family.AddAnimal(this);
        this.species.AddAnimal(this);
    }

    public Class Class
    {
        get
        {
            return this.@class;
        }
    }


    public Family Family
    {
        get
        {
            return this.family;
        }
    }


    public Species Species
    {
        get
        {
            return this.species;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every class down to the actual animal is an abstract class. Tiger is a concrete class which inherits from abstract class Felidae, from abstract class Mammalia, etc.

If you want to get really fancy, you can use interfaces, like IPredator, IWarmBlooded; define them as capabilities.

Comment: Just because you CAN does not mean you SHOULD. Unless there was some concrete reason to define interfaces (you need to treat predators differently than others, for example) you shouldn't go about creating a class or interface for every possible classification.

Comment: Sure, but that's for him to decide. He was asking "how", not "why".

Comment: After looking at his update, it looks more like he should be writing a LINQ provider rather than an object hierarchy, anyhow.